# No se ve contenido de celdas ni nombre de columnas ni seldas #googlesheet

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Como puedo solucionar este inconveniente. Toda sheet que abro se ve de igual forma. Muchas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]